# How can you plot values from different rows on the same line in a dotchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Simple question.
I'm trying to plot two values/means from a data frame on the same line in a dot chart.
One is the mean for men and the other one for women but I would prefer them on the same line.
Also, how can I make the color for the women dot red and men's blue?
Data is something like this

```
df1 <- data.frame(sex = c("F","M"), mean = c(4.3,4.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = mean, y = 1, colour = sex)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1), linetype = "dotted") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("M" = "blue", "F" = "red")) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 5)) +
  labs(y = "") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

[image]